# How can I fix the error "Error: Continuous value supplied to discrete scale"?

Tags: r, ggplot2

My code is

```
ggplot(output1, aes(Year, SuPDem))+
  geom_line(data = filter(output1, v2x_regime == "1"), aes(color = v2x_regime), size = 0.6) +
  geom_line(data = filter(output1, v2x_regime == "0"), aes(color = v2x_regime), size = 0.6) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c('orange', "blue")) +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 5)
```

And my dataset is:

| Index | Year | SuPDem |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1990 | -0.581147 |
| 0 | 1991 | -1.581147 |
| 0 | 1992 | 2.371147 |
| 1 | 1990 | -0.581147 |
| 1 | 1991 | -0.471147 |
| 1 | 1992 | -0.601147 |

I want to have plot two lines where the lines represent 0 and 1 (in the index), labeling 0 as autocracy and 1 as democracy.

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to do what you want is

```
ggplot(output1, aes(Year, SuPDem, color = v2x_regime)) +
   geom_line(size = 0.6) +
   scale_color_manual(values = c("orange", "blue")) + 
   theme_minimal(base_size = 5)
```

That should work as long as `v2x_regime` is a character or factor. If it is an integer, use `color = as.factor(v2x_regime)`.

Presumably `Index` in your quoted data is the same as `v2x_regime`???

Comment: Yes, exactly, Index is v2x_regime.  But still same error is there. When I change the code like that :

'''
ggplot(output1, aes(Year, SuPDem))+
  geom_line(data = filter(output1, v2x_regime == 1), aes(color = v2x_regime), size = 0.6, 
 color="grey") +
  geom_line(data = filter(output1, v2x_regime == 0), aes(color = v2x_regime), size = 0.6, 
  color="darkblue") +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 5)  '''

it works. However, then I cannot label this.

Comment: It sounds like `v2x_regime` is numeric - see added comment in second paragraph above.

Comment: Error in `+.gg`:
! Cannot add ggproto objects together. Did you forget to add this object to a ggplot object?
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Comment: This error appeared